# Running `az artificats` commands from Azure DevOps pipeline YAML file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, package, universal, artifacts

In my Azure Pipelines YAML file, I'm using a Bash task to run a Python script that caches CocoaPods libraries on Azure Artifacts (Universal Packages). I assumed that the Azure command-line tools on the Azure DevOps virtual machines would have the latest Azure extensions installed. I was wrong.

My Python script invokes commands such as `az artifacts universal download` and `az artifacts universal publish`. This works great on my Mac. Not so much on Microsofts VMs.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
##[section]Starting: Bash
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.159.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
./cache_pods.py Debug
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/runner/runners/2.160.1/work/_temp/d0fd889d-a201-42ac-aad6-45ee3eca0532.sh
ERROR: az: 'artifacts' is not in the 'az' command group. See 'az --help'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ERROR: az: 'artifacts' is not in the 'az' command group. See 'az --help'.

You need to install Azure DevOps Extension first then use the az artifacts command.
Please refer to [Azure DevOps CLI in Azure Pipeline YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/azure-devops-cli-in-yaml?view=azure-devops#for-mac-os-azure-pipelines-steps-macyml) for more information.

```
steps:
- script: az extension add -n azure-devops
  displayName: 'Install Azure DevOps Extension'
```

Please add this to your yaml and try again. Hope this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Get same issue After spending an hour get solution :
Without extension, it can't work so try to follow below step:

First try to hit the below command to find the extension

```
az extension add --name azure-devops
```

and then check that extensions is available or not :

Eg. For Pipelines:

```
az extension add --name azure-devops
```

And the run that command